# Hyperledger Fabric: signing channel update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric v2.2 with multiple organizations setup. I want to join a new organization to an existing channel. The problem is in signing channel update.

[Fabric docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html#get-the-necessary-signatures) says that there are two main implementations of signing:

1. “pass it along” - admin of `Org1` signs channel update and sends in to `Org2` admin, `Org2` admin signs and sends to `Org3` and so on, until enough signatures will be collected.
2. "The other option is to submit the update to every Admin on a channel and wait for enough signatures to come back. These signatures can then be stitched together and submitted. This makes life a bit more difficult for the Admin who created the config update (forcing them to deal with a file per signer) but is the recommended workflow for users which are developing Fabric management applications."

All samples that I found describes only the first implementation. But how to do it with the second? I found the related code in [HLF Node.js SDK v1.4](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-create.html) but can't find the same for v2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same doubt, until I saw this [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/security_model.html?highlight=favor#fabric-applications).

> The Fabric v2.x SDKs only support transaction and query functions and event listening. Support for administrative functions for channels and nodes has been removed from the SDKs in favor of the CLI tools.

No more admin function starting from v2.x tho. Not sure if I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing about not finding an example for method 2. However, if you decode a config update on its final stage (when ready to be signed), you'll find there's an array for signatures, like this:

```
"signatures": [
                {
                    "signature": ...",
                    "signature_header": {
                        "creator": {
                            "id_bytes": "...,
                            "mspid": "Org1MSP"
                        },
                        "nonce": "..."
                    }
                }
            ]
```

So you could have copies of the files sign independently, then decode each one of them, and add them that array, and finally encode back again and submit.

Comment: I confirm this is the way. I jest tested edit. You need to do a lot of decode/encode, but you go about adding signatures to that array.

Answer (score 0):

For HF 2.4 and 2.5:

export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"

export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=PATH/TO/ORG1/MSP

./peer channel signconfigtx -f ../channel-artifacts/config_update_in_envelope.pb

Pass it to Org2 and submit the config update with the respective environment variables through the ./peer submit command.